# How do I determine which app is trying to invoke Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

For some reason, Google Chrome was randomly starting up on my system. I uninstalled it, and now I occasionally get the "Choose Application" dialog, which asks "Where is Google Chrome.app?"

How can I determine which application on my machine is trying to invoke Google Chrome?

(Note that I have "Google Chrome Canary" installed, and it is set as my default web browser).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
man iosnoop

man execsnoop

man opensnoop
```

Also possible to get a hint of what's going on running

```
launchctl bslist -j
```

as root, which will show you launchd jobs, -j tells you which job started it,

and

```
launchctl bstree
```

Which shows the jobs running, and under which domain they are running under.

Comment: Did any of these show anything but launchd as the parent process?

Comment: Several launchd's run , one for each user, even users with no shells.  I'll edit the answer though.

Comment: opensnoop in particular will show a file descriptor of -1 for failed opens, which might give insight.

Answer (score 2):

Two places come to mind immediately.

1. Start up Safari and make sure Google Chrome isn't the default browser.
2. Clean up your launch services database.

Since you have already done #1 - redoing it won't likely matter but your safari pref file storing this setting could be corrupt.

Item 2 needs more explanation - Use Finder to right click on a text or html file - if you still see Chrome in the Open With... dialog you might want to [manually rebuild the launch services database](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1912451?threadID=1912451&tstart=0).